# how can i forward and get values of this page to Servlet class?

Tags: html

```
<body>
    <FORM ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION="Test" METHOD=POST>
        <h3><B>Upload IMG Mechanism</B></h3>                  
        <h5>Choose the file To Upload:</h5>
        <INPUT NAME="image" TYPE="file">     
        <br><br>
        <h4><input type="text" name="Cusname"></h4>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File">
    </FORM>
</body>
```

this is my jsp page,How can i get Cusname in Test.java page,if i gave text as hello i need to get Cusname as hello in servlet class,thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with FileUpload - Null Value for Multipart File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713831/problem-with-fileupload-null-value-for-multipart-file)

Comment: What the chnology are you using? Spring-mvc? servlet? other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the values in the servlets by using the following  steps :
  create a servlet name test.java  and write code below

```
String  name= request.getParameter("Cusname"); 
 out.println(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

With something like this if you use spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String upload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("Custname") String cn, Model m) {
    MultipartFile mpf = request.getFileMap().get("file");
    //do want you want
}
```

And add this to your spring XML configuration :

```
<!--require commons-fileupload and commons-io -->
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
```

Comment: You assume the entire Java programming world uses Spring?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to write action in your jsp that will go the servlet that you mapped like below

```
<form action="urServlet" method="post">
```

Then you will get the request parameters from ur jsp to servlet.

```
String Cusname= request.getParameter("Cusname");
```